# Input file for Resharper (NUnit) unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I'd like to take the failures list from an automated unit test run and push it into Resharper or alternatively NUnit GUI. Ideally it would be then up to the user to run the tests manually as they fix them.

I have found some examples on calling NUnit TestSuites/TestFixtures/Tests from code so think that it would be simple enough to parse the output of the test run and then load/or run the failures only.

However I assume there is something to do this kind of thing already - I just can't find it.

Resharper has the ability to export the list of current tests in the session, but I cannot find anything to import a file to create a session. This would seem an obvious and easy solution.

Any one able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is running the whole test suite and then filtering on the failed tests for repeat running of just the failed tests not an option for you in R#?

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  The whole test suite is run in a small test farm and then failures sent to a group of devs. Want to be able to push this failures list back into R# or Nunit. The filtering feature in R# is nice, but not quite what I'm after.

Comment: And you want developers to fix bugs and then not run all tests to see if they didn't break anything else?

Comment: You seem to be searching for a solution to a problem that to me makes no sense. I'm trying to wrap my head around in what situation it would make sense


a) Is it very slow to run all your unit tests
b) Is it not natural for all your developers to always have access to all unit test code + all production code at the same time?
c) Are there issues with Visual Studio (?) and unit testing tool support?
d) Given a bug, feature, piece of production code - is it very hard for a developer to find the unit tests that exercise that feature/code, and if so why?

Comment: @Mahol25 - thanks for trying to wrap your head around this one. I'll try and expand the scenario:

Comment: 1) Entire unit test run takes 90+ mins to run on a test farm. 2) After each test farm run an email is posted to all devs to list failures. 3) Failures for each test run can be from a large number of test classes (100+), with some spread. 4) Devs then need to navigate the tests in local codebase, select each one, run, and then fix for each failed test. Depending on the number of failed tests this selection process can be a 5-25 min job. It is part 4 that I'd like to stream line.

Comment: It's a 'nice to have', but I envision attaching an XML list of the failed tests to the results email and then pushing this straight at NUnit (or R#) to select only the (previously) failed tests. At the moment its a matter of saving some time, but in the future I'd like to use it to do revision based builds of the failed tests to pinpoint who caused failures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extend NUnit framework implement a new attribute which represent certain file path.Resharper only support plain NUnit framework.